# Java ExecutorService, setting an overall fixed rate for all work in a queue

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Given the below code:

```
ScheduledExecutorService es = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(100);

es.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        System.out.println("Do work with a fixed rate! ");
}, 0, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);


int i = 0;
while ( i < 100 ) {
        es.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                System.out.println("Do more work with a fixed rate! Doesn't really work! We will end up with 100 'workers', each running with a fixed rate! ");
        }, 0, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        i++;
}
```

which creates a **SchedueledThreadPoolExecutor**.

In the while loop, we are simulating someone else wanting to add more work to the queue, but this won't obviously work.

I am guessing, that one needs to implement some sort of ThreadPoolExecutor which uses a Queue of some sort, possibly a delayed queue.

The idea is that the executor is created and then it has a fixed rate at which it can execute tasks. If a task finishes too quickly threads that have finished need to wait to do pull off more work.

If one finishes too slowly, then the global time should allow other threads in the threadpool to pull off more work.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractQueue.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html

But I was hoping this was already done, as it should be pretty common problem.

Does anyone have a good solution to this?

Comment: I'm confused. Being a scheduled pool, it will schedule the task to be run at a future time. It won't block each thread until that time comes. The threads are still free to take other tasks scheduled earlier.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Hmm, it can also be used to run tasks at a fixed rate. I guess, what I am after is the ability create a ThreadPool that initially runs with a fixed rate, and then being able to add work to it's queue later on, having it continue to run at a fixed rate. With Schedueled I believe you can run at fixed rate once, but then adding more work I am not sure of. pool.execute will just execute it, because the are no global time limits for the entire threadpool. Do you know? Maybe some sort of delayed queue needs to be used, but I haven't found any good examples.

Comment: I'm still confused. It doesn't matter when you enqueue the work. It will run based on the rate you use (ymmv based on the number of threads and the work you are doing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you want to do, but my guess is that you want a kind of Pacer or Throttler that ensures that tasks are executed with a certain rate (think of the revolving doors found at entrances to office buildings and others, the speed of the door determines the number of persons that can enter (or exit) the building per time unit and the time difference between each entrance (or exit)).

ScheduledExecutorServcice is *not* a solution for that problem. Instead, start by studying the [Leaky Bucket Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket).

Answer (score 0):

A `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` maintains a queue of tasks that is ordered by the tasks' next scheduled execution. These tasks (the `Runnable` instances you provide) are completely independent of the threads that will execute them. In other words, the threads don't just acquire a task, execute it, then go to sleep waiting for that task's next execution.

Instead, the threads poll the queue, acquire a task, execute it, schedule the next execution of their task by reinserting it into the queue, then poll the queue again. If the queue has a task, great. If not, they wait until the next task is ready (whether it's currently in the queue or added at a later time). They then restart this whole process.

All this to say, that a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with 100 threads can easily process more than 100 tasks at any type of rate.